# integrate a function in r (wrong length)

Tags: r

I am facing a problem with the “integrate” command in R and I don’t know how to solve it, so any help how to deal with this is extremely appreciated!

I have some data which I have fitted a function to by using the nls command. I would like to integrate this function over a certain range (e.g. 2-20), which in my case illustrates the fluorescence from 2-20 meters in a water column – could be in any function.

The way I tried to do it:

```
depth <- seq(0,100, by=.1)  
#### First making a vector that simulates depth (Have the real once in my own data set).

flu <- 0.216 + 0.140*depth + (-0.01538*(depth^2)) + 0.0004134*(depth^3)  
### Fitted function.

integrand <- function(depth) {flu}

integrate(integrand, lower= 2, upper= 20)
```

When I do this, R says:
*Error in integrate(integrand, lower = 2, upper = 20) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length*

I have also tried to vectorize the flu function and then integrate again, but it doesn’t help. Maybe it is something with floating points? but I don’t know how to deal with this.

Hope you can help me - thanks for the time and help in advance!!! 
Søren

Comment: You are not calling `flu` inside the function `integrand` and furthermore `flu` is not a function but only an expression.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `nls` to fit this function (a third-order polynomial); you can use `lm(depth~poly(flu,3,raw=TRUE),data)`

Answer (score 3):

```
 depth <- seq(0,100, by=.1)  
 flu <- function(depth) {0.216 + 0.140*depth + (-0.01538*(depth^2)) + 0.0004134*(depth^3) }
 integrate(flu, lower= 2, upper= 20)
#7.170026 with absolute error < 8e-14
```

Comment: Oh thanks!! A little bit embarrassing that I couldn´t see that. But thank you a lot!